# MIPS - Moving graphs

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

The following is my draw image and check input function. Pop and push just macros in Mars that are designed for simplifying prologue and epilogue. I want to use left, right, up, and down in the keyboard to control the moves of the graph that is drawn. I can do left, right, up moves with my current code. Moving down is my problem here. I cannot get the graph shown if include ##1. ##2 lets the graph move automatically down until hits an end. How could I let the graph move downwards like other 3 actions? Also, is there any way to limit the movements within a limited section? like, to limit the x and y coordinate between 3 and 5. (inc for increment and dec for decrement)

```
 draw:
 push ra
 lw a0, xCoordinate
 lw a1, yCoordinate
 la a2, image
 jal    display
 pop ra
 jr ra

 check_input:
 push ra    
 jal    inputKeys
 lw s0, xCoordinate
 lw s1, yCoordinate
 moveLeft:
 and    t0, v0, KEY_LEFT
 beq    t0, 0, moveRight
 dec    s0
 moveRight:
 and    t0, v0, KEY_RIGHT
 beq    t0, 0, moveUp
 inc    s0
 moveUp:
 and    t0, v0, KEY_UP
 beq    t0, 0, moveDown
 dec    s1
 moveDown:
 and    t0, v0, KEY_DOWN
 beq    t0, 0, moveLeft   ##1
 inc    s1                ##2

 sw s0, xCoordinate
 sw s1, yCoordinate

 pop ra
 jr ra
```

Comment: Without a [MCVE] it's hard to say anything but are you sure you want to jump back to `moveLeft` on `##1`? Shouldn't you jump to `sw s0, xCoordinate`?

Comment: yea it works when I changed moveLeft to sw s0, xCoordinate for ##1. Can you explain why?

Comment: Well, otherwise the code enters a loop if you don't press one of the four keys. You can see that each "key-check-section" jumps to the one below in case the test fails. This should be true for the last one as well.